# how to to multiply and divide in a static stack?

Tags: c#, rpn

This is the static array I have been given in making a RPN calculator. From this code the RPN calculator adds and subtracts. Now I need to extend my code to multiply and divide but I cant I don't know how. 
public class IntStack
    {

```
    private const int maxsize = 10;
    private int top = 0;
    private int[] array = new int[maxsize];

    public void Push(int value)
    {
        array[top++] = value;
    }

    public int Pop()
    {

        return array[--top];
    }

    public int Peek()
    {
        return array[top - 1];
    }

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return top == 0;

    }

    public bool IsFull()
    {
        return top == maxsize;
    }




    public string Print()
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = top - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            output.Append(array[i] + Environment.NewLine);
        return output.ToString();
    } 

}
```

Comment: You need to `Pop` two values, multiply them, and then push that result back on to the stack.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some methods you can add to your IntStack class that will perform the multiply and division operations. I've added minimal error checking.

```
    public void Multiply()
    {
        if (array.Length < 2)
            return;

        var factor1 = Pop();
        var factor2 = Pop();
        Push(factor1 * factor2);
    }

    public void Divide()
    {
        if (array.Length < 2)
            return;

        var numerator = Pop();
        var divisor = Pop();

        if (divisor == 0) { // Return stack back to original state.
            Push(divisor);
            Push(numerator);
            return;
        }

        Push(numerator / divisor);
    }
```